# Extended Topological Quantum Field Theory (ETQFT) by Jacob Lurie

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories, quantum-field-theory, higher-category-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory

What is the functorial (categorical) definition of TQFT (Topological Quantum Field Theory), which Jacob Lurie "had extended", for his ETQFT ?

Actually I just need to know what are basic tools, to state properly a categorical definition of a classical TQFT. Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Actually I just need an accurate definition of ETQFT, when truncated in in the level one : For example, "historically" a TQFT is a functor from this category (please give me an accurate definition of this category), to this category (please give me an accurate definition of this other category), such that this functor has this extras structures (please give me an accurate definition of these extras structures). Actually I don't need ETQFT of Jacob Lurie, but just the very "basic" one in dimension 1.

Comment: Have you tried checking out https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extended+topological+quantum+field+theory yet?

Comment: Also, note that $n=1$ will yield exactly what you originally asked, which is just TQFT.

Comment: Ben, I apologies, but I just need an accurate definition of classical TQFT, by using functors : for example in your link they said : 1-categorical TQFT may be regarded as a rule that allows one to compute topological invariants Z(Σ) assigned to d-dimensional manifolds by cutting these manifolds into a sequence {Σi} of d-dimensional composable cobordisms with (d−1)-dimensional boundaries ∂Σi, e.g. Σ=Σ2∐∂Σ1=∂Σ2Σ1, then assigning quantities Z(Σi) to each of these and then composing these quantities in some way, e.g. as Z(Σ)=Z(Σ2)∘Z(Σ1); etc. But they do not define what is this functor

Comment: they do not say : this is a functor F : C----->D, where C is a category build like that, D is a category build like that, F on objects is like that and on morphisms is like that ...

Comment: "may be regarded as a rule that allows one to compute topological invariants Z(Σ) " what are these topological invariant : Singular cohomology ? Others ? What they mean, when they say "rule" ?

Comment: Their formula : Σ=Σ2∐∂Σ1=∂Σ2Σ1, is too fuzzy for me : May you provide me a better formulation, clearer ?

Comment: Thank you very much again !

Answer (score 1):

This is just one definition of a TQFT. There are many more, but this is the one I personally have encountered before:
Let $\mathbf{Bord}(n+1)$ be the category with objects closed, oriented, smooth $n$-manifolds and for $Y_1, Y_2$ two objects in this category, $Hom(Y_1,Y_2)$ be the set of $(n+1)$ bordism classes between $Y_1$ and $Y_2$. An $(n+1)$-TQFT is a symmetric monoidal functor from $\mathbf{Bord}(n+1)$ to the category $\mathbf{Vec}_{\mathbb{C}}$ of finite dimensional complex vector spaces.

More specifically: an $(n+1)$-TQFT is a pair $F=(V,Z)$ where $V(Y)$ assigns a finite dimensional complex vector space to a closed, oriented, smooth $n$-manifold $Y$ and $Z$ assigns to each $(n+1)$-bordism $X$ between two $Y_-,Y_+\in\mathbf{Bord}(n+1)$ a linear map $Z(X):V(Y_-)\to V(Y_+)$ such that:

1. If $X$ and $X'$ belong to the same bordism class, then $Z(X)=Z(X')$.
2. $Z(Y\times I)=id_{V(Y)}$
3. $Z(X_1\cup X_2)=Z(X_2)\circ Z(X_1):V(Y_1)\to V(Y_2)\to V(Y_3)$
4. $V(\emptyset)\cong\mathbb{C}$
5. $V(Y_1\sqcup Y_2)\cong V(Y_1)\otimes V(Y_2)$ with the following diagrams commuting:
   $$\require{AMScd}
   \begin{CD}
   V((Y_1\sqcup Y_2)\sqcup Y_3) @>{\cong}>> (V(Y_1)\otimes V(Y_2))\otimes V(Y_3);\\
   @VVV @VVV \\
   V(Y_1\sqcup( Y_2\sqcup Y_3)) @>{\cong}>> V(Y_1)\otimes(V(Y_2)\otimes V(Y_3));
   \end{CD}$$

   $$\require{AMScd}
   \begin{CD}
   V(\emptyset\sqcup Y) @>{\cong}>> \mathbb{C}\otimes V(Y);\\
   @VVV @VVV \\
   V(Y) @>{=}>> V(Y);
   \end{CD}$$
6. There is an isomorphism $V(Y_1\sqcup Y_2)\cong V(Y_2\sqcup Y_1)$ such that the following diagram commutes:
   $$\require{AMScd}
   \begin{CD}
   V(Y_1\sqcup Y_2) @>{\cong}>> V(Y_1)\otimes V(Y_2);\\
   @VVV @VVV \\
   V(Y_2\sqcup Y_1) @>{\cong}>> V(Y_2)\otimes V(Y_1);
   \end{CD}$$

Subject to these axioms, the functor $F=(V,Z)$ can be anything we like; what we take it to be determines the TQFT we are looking at. There is a theorem which says that: $Z(M)$ is a smooth invariant for closed $(n+1)$-manifolds $M$ and $V(Y)$ is a representation of the mapping class group of $Y$. As far as I am aware, given a TQFT $F=(V,Z)$, it is still an open (and very difficult) question to determine exactly how $F$ relates to 'classical' invariants such as, for example, homology groups or homotopy groups.